# Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm developing ecommerce, for this I'm using MERN, and when the user places an order, the order model takes the id on the user and through this id I can get the user's name and show it on my frontend. so far everything is working perfectly. but when I delete a user who has already placed an order and I try to view the orders. I'm getting this error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'name' of null.
[image]

> because the user with this id was not found.

*is there any way to resolve this or not receive this error?*

```
//Node.js
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [CartItemSchema],
    transaction_id: {},
    amount: { type: Number },
    address: String,
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: "Não está em andamento",
      enum: ["Não está em andamento", "Em andamento", "Já enviado", "Concluido", "Cancelado"] // enum means string objects
    },
    updated: Date,
      //this line makes reference to the model user
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```
//React
export const listOrders = (userId, token) =>{
        return fetch(`${API}/order/list/${userId}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer said, you need to nullcheck every object along the chain, alternatively, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid cumbersome code like so:

```js
return (
  <td>{o?.user?.name` || 'some name`}</td>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to nullcheck the user object also:

```
{ (o.user && o.user.name) ? o.user.name : 'abc' }
```